# Enviar ID por GET

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actualmente estoy trabajando con codeigniter y estoy pasando un parametro de la siguiente manera:

```html
<p><a href="<?= base_url()?>session/documentos/<?= $id_cur_ses ?>"><strong>DOCUMENTOS</strong></a><br>
```

El tema es que en la siguiente pagina aparece el ID en la URL y si alguien lo modifica automaticamente se refresca con los datos del ID que modifico, mi consulta es:
Como hago para que no pase esto ? Osea que cuando alguien modifique se cancele la transaccion o no muestre datos.

Answer (score 1):

dependiendo como funcione la aplicación y lo que quieras/necesites hacer, puedes usar una o varias de estas al tiempo:

- No usar GET. Puedes usar POST, PUT, etc. dependiendo lo que necesites y no verás la ID en la URL, sin embargo hacer una solicitud por POST cambiando el ID puede no ser tan complicado.
- Utiliza la sesión de PHP para almacenar el Id actual y no dejes ver otros en un momento determinado, según la lógica de tu aplicación.
- Crea/utliza permisos dentro de tu aplicación, por ejemplo: el usuario solo tiene acceso a los ID que él mismo creó.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza encrypt de la siguiente manera:

```
<?= base_url();?>session/documentos/<?=$this->encrypt->encode($id_cur_ses);?>
```

Pero antes de eso, tienes que activar la librería en el autoload de la siguiente manera:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('encrypt');
```

Espero te haya servido, Saludos! ;)!

Comment: Muchas gracias Jean Paul.

Comment: De nada, Saludos!